# How to upgrade my Azure SDK version for .NET Application

Tags: azure, azure-sdk-.net, azure-sdk

My current Azure Tools Version is 2.9. How do I update the whole tool version to 3.0+?

I tried installing Azure SDK for .NET however it is giving me options to install single packages (https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk/). However I am unable to find "authoring tools", "Azure tools" and "libs for .net" packages. How do I install these packages?
My current Azure .NET SDK version is 2.9. (as checked from file system C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\.NET SDK\v2.9\)

And if I don't want to install specific packages but the upgraded Azure SDK all together. Is this possible? If yes the how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no modern equivalent to the old v2.9 installer, that was the last version released as a local bundle and has long been unsupported.

The modern Azure SDK is not an installable toolset; it is a series of NuGet packages that can be referenced by your application to interact with different Azure services.